# Use class name to name interface properties

Tags: typescript

I think this [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oCcCmYAJgPYB2I80YAXOgEa2kCuAtnXjgL7QC860DaAEYATAGZonANwYs0YGQgAXHE2BLiOABQBKdHOxKAFgEsIAOjDm6vYTOycMjjAHoX0FfCEYTpJRwAzMGA8aABBdRNFfWwAbQRkSAtSMBZQgGpoAHIAfWClKNIhLIBdWmUcXwBzABo5eKQUZNSM7LzIshFSxlZ2HCdZX38cIJDwjtIIERi4RqT2grIhcpVquuwEpoXCkR62DgHXdzwADwAHPHUqKlJCAQ9iATwjMAA3UONQiBaMBUmlKi0CKLSbTPiYDZzKDbJa0LIAFiy61miWh+R2tG8zj+ygEQImMHBck283RsOyiORJLRE12wicQA) shows what Im trying to achieve:

I want to use `Class.name` as a variable to name my properties.

```
class MyClass {
  readonly a: {b: number} = { b: 123 };

  constructor() {
    this.a.b = 1;
  }
}

// try1
interface Actions {
  [MyClass.name + '_action1']: string,
  [MyClass.name + '_action2']: number
}

interface Actions2 {
  MyClass_action1: string,
  MyClass_action2: number
}

// expect a and b to behave the same
const a: Actions2 = {
  MyClass_action1: '4',
  MyClass_action2: 1
}

const b: Actions = {
  MyClass_action1: '4',
  MyClass_action2: 1
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: See [ms/TS#43325](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43325); class names are not given literal types in TypeScript; you can only see `string` there (which is the best that can be done without breaking class hierarchies).  You can kind of sort of fake it by telling the compiler that `MyClass.name` is of type `"MyClass"`, and then you have to do other indirections, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wRjv1w).  Not sure if that's worth it, though.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: if its really not possble without workarounds/ hacks then I guess you have answered it. Thank you so far. I guess I like your github -issue static property solution the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible without workarounds.

The `name` property of class constructors is of type `string`, as inherited [from the `Function` interface](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/7a1f97a61bb5c73b52aa60797d062ff67bd81c51/src/lib/es2015.core.d.ts#L73-L78). The compiler doesn't know the `string` [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the `name`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#43325](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43325) and the issues to which it links.

Assuming that we know for sure that at runtime, a `class Foo {⋯}` will have `Foo.name === "Foo"` (meaning that we don't worry about weird edge cases where [it is overridden by a `static` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#examples) or where the class is minified or mangled, etc), TypeScript still can't easily allow the type of `Foo.name` to be `"Foo"`.  That's because the static side of a class forms a type hierarchy, so if you have `class Bar extends Foo {⋯}`, then TypeScript expects `Bar.name` to be assignable to `Foo.name`.  So if `Foo.name` is of type `"Foo"` then `Bar.name` also needs to be of type `"Foo"`.  But that's quite unlikely to be true at runtime.  Essentially there's a whole mess surrounding static inheritance that TypeScript mostly tries to avoid, leading to somewhat less strong types than people would like.

It's vaguely possible that someday JavaScript will introduce a `nameof` operator like C# has, and then TypeScript will support that (see [microsoft/TypeScript#1579](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1579)), and then we can extract the name of a class in the TypeScript type system in some officially supported way.

But until and unless any of these happen, you're stuck specifying it yourself.  You can do so by manually merging the information in, like this:

```
declare namespace MyClass {
  export const name: "MyClass"
}
```

And then you can define your keys via [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) (that's the only way to get string concatenation at the type level):

```
const action1 = `${MyClass.name}_action1` as const;
const action2 = `${MyClass.name}_action2` as const;
interface Actions {
  [action1]: string,
  [action2]: number
}
```

This may or may not meet your needs, but for now, it's either do something like this, or give up.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.1.6#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcVoG8BQ1oCcCmYAJgPYB2I80YAXOtAEa2kCuAtvXjtAL7QC8dRtACMAJgDMPANxZowMhAAuOZsEXEcACgCU6WdkUALAJYQAdGDP1+Imdm4YHhPKDD5opMKzwQADmGA8OCQUGExsPAAPXw1FOQU4z29aACIEZEgIFMcMeVIlKjVjMmEbAAMAEjR00LMkvG4AfQDFYtJhMqoYPKUZHriWttFyqprMuq8G5qKyUU7IePzFGWNSRU4AMwCggEEZ-L1sAG1BkoBdWiUcVYBzABpZE-3RC482Dhwc3ISGWj3WhQ2cLBDJQaYA9q0ADkABYoQ9sGMwadSKJaMJHDIMEA)